# Twilio - What do the different "speechModel" values mean in the Gather command?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

The Twilio [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#speechmodel) states that the valid values for `speechModel`are:

- `default`
- `numbers_and_commands`
- `phone_call`

I think I have a slight understanding for `phone_call`, but what do the `default` and `numbers_and_commands` mean?

I'm trying to build a bot that will take commands and answers to prompts as in the question [Problems with verb Record timeout when calling an IVR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049380/problems-with-verb-record-timeout-when-calling-an-ivr?rq=1), but the Gather documentation doesn't specify what each value means. I would think that for my use case, "numbers_and_commands" should do it, but I would appreciate more concrete definitions about the behaviors for each value.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some additional details on the Twilio Gather speechModel attribute:

Phone call
phone_call (en-US only)
Use this model for transcribing audio from a phone call. Typically, phone audio is recorded at 8,000Hz sampling rate.

Numbers and Command
numbers_and_command (all available languages)
Use this model for transcribing shorter audio clips. Some examples include voice commands or voice search.

Default 
default (all available languages)
Use this model if your audio does not fit one of the previously described models. For example, you can use this for long-form audio recordings that feature a single speaker only.